# DAX - formula for lost customers

Tags: pivot-table, dax

Been using [Javier Guillens](https://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/determining-customer-retention-in-dax/) formula for Lost Customers and it's working great. Problem is though I want customers to be considered lost after 3 months of no transactions rather than one. How would I do that?

Also, another problem is when I try to make it a pivot table I can see the number of lost customers for each month but I cant see which customers. Because when I try to put CustomerID as rows so I can see each customerID per month nothing happens. There is an expand icon but when I click it nothing happens. Do you happen to know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This is pretty much the best source](http://www.daxpatterns.com/new-and-returning-customers/) for all sorts of new/returning/lost customer measures, with full explanations and templates. Their lost customer measure can be used with arbitrary periods.

Comment: I've been using that for new customers but their lost customers is too messy. Javier Guillens works great except for my two minor problems.